# Datasets with long tail of eigenvalues of the covariance?

Tags: distributions, dataset, covariance

In most datasets I use, the spectrum of the covariance matrix decays to 0 quite fast, meaning that they are more or less low-rank.

My question is, whether there are setting or disciplines that are known to have datasets with a long-tail of eigenvalues?